# r h2o package 3.6.0.3. How do I sort an H2O frame by column?

Tags: r, h2o

I am using the r h2o package 3.6.0.3. I cannot update to a newer version. How do I sort an h2o frame by a certain  column? I've looked through the manual [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/3/docs-website/h2o-r/h2o_package.pdf), but I was unable to find a sort function.

Thank you!

Comment: can we see the code you're using to make that h2o frame?

Comment: the code to make the h2o frame does not really matter imho

Answer (score 1):

In the h2o R package, we have the `h2o.arrange()` method which will sort an H2OFrame by a column or columns.  This is similar to `dplyr::arrange()`.  However, this is broken for floats right now (integers work fine).  The ticket for fixing the "sort on a float column" functionality is here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3525

Comment: Thanks, Frank.  I've updated the JIRA.  Also see my updated answer above.

Comment: I specifically mention that I am using R package version 3.6 which does not have the h2o.arrange function that 3.10 has.

Comment: Ok, I did not recall off the top of my head which version of H2O that `h2o.arrange()` function was first introduced, but it sounds like you are out of luck until you upgrade.  The work-around is to do the sorting in an R data.frame or data.table and use the `as.h2o(df)` function to send the sorted frame to H2O.  The other alternative is to use Spark / sparklyr to do the sorting if your data is too big for a single machine's memory in R.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid would be the case. If you update your answer, then I will accept it.